Help finding a horror movie set in Japan?
I believe it was released late 2000s and released in the U.S. It was set in Japan (hence title). I saw this a while ago so my memory might not be serving me well but a couple of things that happened stood out to me:
A family visiting Japan during a time where you would burn sacrifices for spirits to receive in the afterlife? It was a white family, I think, and the boy was able to see a ghost eating an orange in the middle of the street. 
I don't remember the plot but the biggest thing that stood out was a female spirit with black hair that wore a yellow? dress with oil on her arms. There was a flashback of her dipping her arms into oil in some underground place with other people when an old woman sticks a butcher knife into her head to kill her. You can see the scar on her spirit. 
Then in the end the old woman is crowded by the ghost of the girl and all of those people that were in the underground place when she died. The woman coughs up a tooth and gets killed. 
Please tell me this was an actual film and that I didn't hallucinate it. I've been trying to find it for years now.

Just to be sure, is this a Japanese or American movie?

Could it be "They Wait" from Ernie Barbarash?  It is influenced by Chinese traditions (not Japanese) concerning the Hungry Ghost Festival to show veneration and filial piety towards the dead, which includes offering food and "money" to those who have passed away.  It does have a girl with long black hair dipping her arms into a black substance in a secret warehouse.
